# what's the nature of this error in Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, nhibernate

```
Unknown column 'user0_.Id' in 'field list'

Description:       An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current
                   web request. Please review the stack trace for more information
                   about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Unknown column 'user0_.Id'
                   in 'field list'

Source Error: 


Line 31:         public  ActionResult Login(AuthLogin formlogin,string returnurl)    
Line 32:         {    
Line 33:             var MUser = Database.Session.Query<user>().FirstOrDefault(u => 
u.username == formlogin.Username);    
Line 34:             if(MUser==null)    
Line 35:                 user.FakeHash()
```

the error is in  line no 33

Answer (score 0):

Without your NHibernate mapping and some snippets about the underlying MySQL Table structure, it is hard to judge.

But as the exceptions says, NHibernate created such query, which in its SELECT cluase *(the 'field list')* generates the name which does not exist (`SELECT user0_.Id` ... ).

The possible reasons could be:

- wrong mapping. `id` column should be e.g. **`User_ID`**
- fluent mapping and some convention expecting ID column beeing named as id - Change the convention ar mapp the ID explicitly
- be sure that Database is not set into case sensitive mode (ID instead of id)

*If these hints are not enough, do not hesitate and extend the question with more/mapping details*